# Factoring a polynomial into linear factors by ring extension

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

The following sounds so natural, I'm surprised I have never asked it before:

> **Question 1.** Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Let $P \in R\left[X\right]$ be a polynomial. Can we find a commutative ring $S$ that contains $R$ as a subring, and a bunch of elements $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_m, b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_m \in S$ such that $P = \left(a_1 X + b_1\right) \left(a_2 X + b_2\right) \cdots \left(a_m X + b_m\right)$ in $S\left[X\right]$ ?

In other words, can every polynomial over a commutative ring be factored as a product of polynomials of degree $\leq 1$ over a possibly larger commutative ring?

The answer to this question is known to be positive if $P$ is monic (here, it suffices to adjoin the roots of $P$ to $R$ one by one, using the standard $R\left[X\right] / \left(P\right)$ construction). Thus, by mirroring, the answer is also positive if the constant term of $P$ is $1$.

I suspect that the answer in the general case is negative. However, perhaps above two positive cases can be combined under the following general roof:

> **Question 2.** Assume that the content of $P$ (that is, the ideal of $R$ generated by the coefficients of $P$) is the whole $R$. Is the answer to Question 1 positive?

An example for Question 2 would be the polynomial $2X^2 + X + 2$ over $R = \mathbb{Z}/8$. Over $R = \mathbb{Z} / 4$, the same polynomial factors as $\left(2X+1\right)\left(X+2\right)$ even without extending the ring.

An example for Question 1 that seems particularly suited to disprove it might be the polynomial $\alpha X^2 + \beta X + \alpha$ over $R = \mathbb{Q}\left[\alpha, \beta\right] / \left(\alpha, \beta\right)^2$. But it's one thing to come up with the polynomial, another to actually prove that it does not factor into linear factors...

Comment: Do you have any example where the "just do it" solution does not work? To take your example at the end, let $S = (\mathbb{Z}/8 \mathbb{Z})[a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2] / \langle a_1 a_2-2, a_1 b_2+a_2 b_1-1, b_1 b_2 - 2 \rangle$. Does $\mathbb{Z}/8 \mathbb{Z}$ not inject into $S$?

Comment: For the particular example of $2x^2+x+2$, this factors over $\mathbb{Z}/8 \mathbb{Z}$ as $(2x+5)(x+2)$. More generally, $-15$ is a square in the $2$-adics; let $\sqrt{-15}$ denote the $2$-adic square root of $-15$ which is $1 \bmod 4$. Then the factorization $2x^2+x+2 = (x-\tfrac{-1+\sqrt{-15}}{4})(2x-\tfrac{-1-\sqrt{-15}}{2})$ gives a factorization in $\mathbb{Z}/2^k \mathbb{Z}$ for any $k$.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: Oh, good point; hadn't thought out the powers of $2$. But I am not very hopeful about the "just do it" approach. Gröbner bases over (non-field) rings do not always exist, and this question is very much concerned with the cases where they don't (leading term is a zero-divisor).

Comment: @darijgrinberg Formally, $(\beta X + \alpha)(\alpha X/\beta + 1) = \alpha X^2 + \beta X + \alpha$ because $\alpha^2 = 0$. Can this be made rigorous?

Comment: @TimothyChow: Not sure how, given that $\beta$ is nilpotent..

Comment: @darijgrinberg You can make Timothy Chow's claim rigorous by introducing a scale parameter: work in $R[t]/(\alpha-t\beta)$.

Comment: @JacobManaker I agree, and then the question becomes whether $R\to R[t]/(\alpha-t\beta)$ is injective (and whether the trick can be generalized).

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly: The map is injective; as a $\mathbb{Q}$-module, $R$ is spanned by $\{1,\alpha,\beta\}$, which are linearly independent in $R[t]/(\alpha-t\beta)$.

Comment: @JacobManaker Could you please elaborate? Following my nose, I let $I$ be the ideal $\langle \alpha^2, \alpha\beta, \beta^2, \alpha-t\beta\rangle$ and I set $S := \mathbb{Q}[\alpha, \beta, t]/I$. I want to claim that in $S[X]$, we have $(\beta X + \alpha)(tX + 1) = \alpha X^2 + \beta X + \alpha$. Naively, I want to claim that $\alpha t\in I$, but this is false. Maybe we just throw $\alpha t$ into $I$ as well?

Comment: @TimothyChow: Yes, one needs to add $\alpha t\in I$.  I originally worked in $R[t]/(\alpha-t\beta,t^2)$, thought I didn't need the $(t^2)$, and I guess I was wrong (sorry).

Comment: I'm leaning heavily on the fact that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ aren't just zero divisors, but nilpotent, and I don't see a way to remove the obstruction.  A possible counterexample seems like $xT^2+yT+z$ over $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z,a]/(xa,ya,za,wa)$.

Comment: @JacobManaker What happens if we try David Speyer's construction? Take $$A = \mathbb{C}[x,y,z,a,a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2]/\langle xa,ya,za,a_1a_2-x,a_1b_2+a_2b_1-y,b_1b_2-z\rangle.$$ Then in $A[T]$ we have $xT^2+yT+z = (a_1 T + b_1)(a_2T+ b_2)$.

Comment: @TimothyChow: I don't see why the $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z,a]/(xa,ya,za)$ necessarily injects into that set.

Comment: @JacobManaker Worst case, one can use a Groebner basis to calculate an elimination ideal, right? Though this might not give insight into whether the construction generalizes.

Comment: @TimothyChow: The $K\left[a\right]$-algebra homomorphism $f:K\left[x,y,z,a\right] / \left(xa,ya,za\right) \to K\left[x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,a\right] / \left(x_1a, x_2a, y_1a, y_2a\right) $ that sends $x,y,z$ to $x_1x_2, x_1y_2+x_2y_1, y_1y_2$, respectively (thus sending $xt^2 + yt + z \mapsto \left(x_1t+y_1\right)\left(x_2t+y_2\right)$), is injective. This is best seen using a multigrading that assigns degree $\left(0,2\right)$ to each of $x,y,z$, degree $\left(1,0\right)$ to $a$, and degree $\left(0,1\right)$ to each of $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$. Then, $f$ is graded, and both source ...

Comment: ... and target have all their degree-$\left(i,j\right)$ components vanish when $i$ and $j$ are both positive.

Answer (score 11):

The answer to Question 2 is yes. As observed, it is the case if the constant term is 1, or more generally invertible.
By translation, this is also true if there is $t\in R$ such that $P(t)\in R^\times$. (In fact, in these cases we can take $S$ finite free, in particular faithfully flat,  over $R$).
Now, in general, let $t$ be an indeterminate and consider
$$R_1:=R[t, P(t)^{-1}].$$
By construction, we have $P(t)\in R_1^\times$ so $P$ can be factored over some finite free overring $S$ of $R_1$.

Geometrically, $\mathrm{Spec}(R_1)\subset \mathbb{A}^1_R$ is the open complement of the hypersurface defined by $P(t)$. Thus, to say that $P$ has content ideal $c(P)=R$ just means that $\mathrm{Spec}(R_1)$ is surjective (hence faithfully flat) over $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$. Consequently, $R\to R_1\to S$ is then faithfully flat, in particular injective. Note that it can be injective in other cases, but I suspect that faithful flatness is the really useful condition.

Comment: The first paragraph is brilliant. I cannot follow the second paragraph, as I don't know the alg/geo dictionary you are tacitly using. That said, it appears that all that needs to be actually proved is that $P\left(t\right)$ is a non-zero-divisor in $R\left[t\right]$, but that follows from [McCoy's theorem](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/068P). Thus, we can even loosen our assumption "the content of $P$ is $R$" to "the content of $P$ is a faithful $R$-submodule of $R$". Nice!!

Comment: (I'll wait with the checkmark for a couple days -- maybe someone will destroy question 1 in the meantime.)

Comment: My argument for faithful flatness can be phrased as follows: for each maximal ideal $m$ of $R$, we have $R_1/mR_1\cong (R/m)[t,\overline{P}(t)^{-1}]$ where $\overline{P}=P\bmod m[t]$. If $P$ is primitive, $\overline{P}$ is nonzero, so $R_1/mR_1\neq0$. Since $R\to R_1$ is obviously flat, it is faithfully flat.

Comment: About $P$ being a nonzerodivisor: this is indeed sufficient to get injectivity, but not faithful flatness in general. This is the sort of thing I was thinking about at the end of my answer.

Comment: @darijgrinberg if you only care about injectivity of the composite $A\to A[t]\to A[t,1/f(t)]$, can't you circumvent McCoy's theorem? It seems sufficient to say that for $a\in A$ the fraction $\tfrac a1$ is zero in the localization iff its annihilated by a power of $f$, recovering your condition that the content of $f$ be a faithful ideal.

Comment: @Arrow: How does it recover my condition? (Keep in mind that the content of a power of $f$ is not necessarily a power of the content of $f$, and the proof of Dedekind-Mertens is more complicated than that of McCoy.)